# Preventing the colon from causing indentation to be deleted

Tags: indentation, filetype-c

When opening a C file, then even with the vanilla setup on my Linux Mint system, if I type `identifier` at the beginning of an indented line and then ':'
immediately after it, the indentation for that line gets deleted.

How can I disable this behavior?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file)

Comment: @Matt Nice of you to be so condescending. I had done `HOME=$PWD vi testfile.c` in an empty directory so I'm pretty sure it's not a problem of debugging my (empty) `.vimrc`. But this `cindent` option is pointing me in the right direction, so thanks! ;-)

Comment: `cindent` must not be set by default. Setting `HOME=$PWD` is wrong, as it still allows processing `/usr/share/vim` and such. That is, your problem is broken installation / altered runtime files.

Comment: @Matt The system files are exactly as they came from the package manager of my system (which might not be vanilla enough for some definitions of the word). The `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N` recommended in the link you posted works to suppress the behavior, though. Useful info. Thank you.

Comment: This is strange, since `cindent` should not be enabled for non-C filetypes, only C filetypes and a few very similar languages (where this is expected, as `text:` is treated as a label). Are you sure there's no vimrc file in ~/.vimrc or ~/.vim/vimrc? Or maybe there's a plugin or something in the `~/.vim/pack` directory? On which system are you using Vim? Maybe they ship with a weird non-standard configuration? You can also check where it was set with `:20verbose set cindent`, and see which files are loaded with `:scriptnames`.

Comment: The command to check where it was set is `:20verbose set consent?`, with the `?` asking to query what the option is set to and the `:verbose` asking where it was set.

Comment: @MartinTournoij Thanks. With an empty .vimrc-less $HOME, it only happened with C files and  `:20verbose set cindent?` showed  `/usr/share/vim/vim80/indent/c.vim` as the culprit (I guess that's what my system, Linux Mint 19.3, provides). Textfiles were only affected with my real `.vimrc`, which also had `set cindent` in it.

Comment: Ah right, so you do have a vimrc file then? I'm a bit confused because before you said it's empty? At any rate, don't add that in your vimrc: it's only intended to be set for specific filetypes such as C. Then you don't need to frob with `cinkeys` either. This setting is very old and goes back to before Vim had a generic indentation system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My vanilla vim setup (empty `.vimrc`) had the `cindent` option on an the related
`cinkeys` option set to (the default) `cinkeys=0{,0},0),:,0#,!^F,o,O,e`.

Removing the `:` from the list disables the reindenting behavior associated with `:`.

More info is available with `:help 'cindent'`.

Thanks to [Matt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/22797/matt) for pointing me in the right direction!